# How to use composite file writer for jdbc or writing data to database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have written a composite item writer for writing to the flat file, but I want to write in database also if certain condition meet. So, how can I do that... I am a  beginner. Kindly help..

**Composite file writer class:**

```
@Component("CompositeFileWriter")
```

public class ChargeBackCompositeFileWriter implements ItemStreamWriter{

```
@Autowired
private PartOrderDao partOrderDao;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("errorFileWriter")
private ItemStreamWriter<ChargeBack> errorFileWriter;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("retryFileWriter")
private ItemStreamWriter<ChargeBack> retryFileWriter;



@Autowired
@Qualifier("processedFileWriter")
private ItemStreamWriter<ChargeBack> processedFileWriter;




@Override
public void write(List<? extends ChargeBack> items) throws Exception {
    
    
    
    List<ChargeBack> errorRecords = items.stream().filter(ChargeBack::isBadRecord).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<ChargeBack> retryRecords = items.stream().filter(ChargeBack::isRetryRecord)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    List<ChargeBack> processedRecords = items.stream()
            .filter(chargeBack -> !chargeBack.isBadRecord())
            .filter(chargeBack-> !chargeBack.isRetryRecord())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    
    
    
    //ChargeBack chargeBack = new ChargeBack();

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(errorRecords)) {
        errorFileWriter.write(errorRecords);
    }

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(processedRecords)) {
        processedFileWriter.write(processedRecords);
    }
    
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(retryRecords)) {
        
    }
}


@Override
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    errorFileWriter.open(executionContext);
    processedFileWriter.open(executionContext);
    //retryFileWriter.open(executionContext);
}

@Override
public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    errorFileWriter.update(executionContext);
    processedFileWriter.update(executionContext);
    //retryFileWriter.update(executionContext);
}

@Override
public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
    errorFileWriter.close();
    processedFileWriter.close();
    //retryFileWriter.close();
}
```

}

**BatchConfg file**

```
@Bean
public ItemStreamWriter<ChargeBack> processedFileWriter(
        @Value("${processed.file}") FileSystemResource processedFile) {
    FlatFileItemWriter<ChargeBack> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(processedFile);
    writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<ChargeBack>() {
        {
            setDelimiter("|");
            setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<ChargeBack>() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { ""
                              });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return writer;
}

//for reading retry file and passing it, for writing record to the table.
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader retryFileReader(@Value("${input.retryFile}") FileSystemResource inputFile){
    FlatFileItemReader reader = new FlatFileItemReader();
    reader.setResource(inputFile);
    reader.setLinesToSkip(0);
    reader.setStrict(false);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper(){
        {setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper(){{
         setTargetType(ChargeBack.class);}});
         setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(){{
         setNames(new String[]{""});
         setDelimiter("|");}});}});
    return reader;
}


 @Bean
 public JdbcBatchItemWriter retryFileWriterToDB(){
     JdbcBatchItemWriter writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter ();
     writer.setDataSource(pdccRepositoryConfig.pdccDataSource());
     writer.setSql(")" +
             " values (?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ");
     writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new ItemPreparedStatementSetter<ChargeBack>() {
         @Override
         public void setValues(ChargeBack item, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
             ps.setString(1, item.getAccertifyCBControlNumber().toString());
             ps.setString(2,item.getInternalComment2());
             ps.setString(3, item.getDisputeType());
             ps.setString(4, item.getBrand());
             ps.setString(5,item.getResolution1ts());
             ps.setString(6, item.getReasonCode());
             ps.setString(7, item.getReasonDescription());
             ps.setString(8,item.getWonLossStatus());
             ps.setString(9, item.getDisputedDate());
             ps.setString(10, Double.toString(item.getDisputedAmount()));
             ps.setString(11, item.getReportingGroup());
             ps.setString(12, item.getDueDate());
             ps.setString(13,item.getLocation());
             ps.setString(14, item.getResolution1ts());
             ps.setString(15, item.getTransactionDate());
            
         }

        
     });

     return writer;

 }
```

**I am currently writing separately in database  using above jdbcbatchitemwriter, but i want it to be used by streamitemwriter, so as i can write on same time, instead of writing seperately.
My question in sort is I want to use this jdbcbatchitemwriter to be used by streamitemwriter, like above I m using flat file item writer's.
And If I cannot use jdbcbatchitemwriter in streamwriter then what is the next solution. kindly elaborate it if possible..**

Answer (score 0):

So, to use JDBCitemwriter with compositeitemwriter, just make your JdbcitemWriter return type to itemwriter.

```
 @Bean 
 public ItemWriter retryFileWriterToDB(){
  JdbcBatchItemWriter writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter ();
     writer.setDataSource(pdccRepositoryConfig.pdccDataSource());
     writer.setSql("insert into failed_forter_claim_api_order (accertify_cb_control_number, internal_comment2, dispute_type, brand, resolution1_name, reason_code, reason_description, won_loss_status, disputed_date, disputed_amount, reporting_group, due_date, location, resolution1_ts, transaction_date)" +
             " values (?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ");
     writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new ItemPreparedStatementSetter<ChargeBack>() {
         @Override
         public void setValues(ChargeBack item, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
             ps.setString(1, item.getAccertifyCBControlNumber().toString());
             ps.setString(2,item.getInternalComment2());
             ps.setString(3, item.getDisputeType());
             ps.setString(4, item.getBrand());
             ps.setString(5,item.getResolution1ts());
             ps.setString(6, item.getReasonCode());
             ps.setString(7, item.getReasonDescription());
             ps.setString(8,item.getWonLossStatus());
             ps.setString(9, item.getDisputedDate());
             ps.setString(10, Double.toString(item.getDisputedAmount()));
             ps.setString(11, item.getReportingGroup());
             ps.setString(12, item.getDueDate());
             ps.setString(13,item.getLocation());
             ps.setString(14, item.getResolution1ts());
             ps.setString(15, item.getTransactionDate());
            
         }

        
     });

     return writer;

 }
```

2. autowire in your compositeItemwriter like below, u can prefer retryFileWriterToDB as a keyword, how I used it in below code.

@Component("CompositeFileWriter")
public class ChargeBackCompositeFileWriter implements ItemStreamWriter{

```
@Autowired
private PartOrderDao partOrderDao;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("errorFileWriter")
private ItemStreamWriter<ChargeBack> errorFileWriter;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("retryFileWriterToDB")
private ItemWriter<ChargeBack> retryFileWriterToDB;



@Autowired
@Qualifier("processedFileWriter")
private ItemStreamWriter<ChargeBack> processedFileWriter;




@Override
public void write(List<? extends ChargeBack> items) throws Exception {
    

    
    List<ChargeBack> errorRecords = items.stream().filter(ChargeBack::isBadRecord).collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<ChargeBack> retryRecords = items.stream().filter(ChargeBack::isRetryRecord)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    List<ChargeBack> processedRecords = items.stream()
            .filter(chargeBack -> !chargeBack.isBadRecord())
            .filter(chargeBack-> !chargeBack.isRetryRecord())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    
    
    
    //ChargeBack chargeBack = new ChargeBack();

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(errorRecords)) {
        errorFileWriter.write(errorRecords);
    }

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(processedRecords)) {
        processedFileWriter.write(processedRecords);

    }
    
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(retryRecords)) {
        
        System.out.println("writing ti DB:..");
    //  System.out.println("Calling partdao.......");
        //partOrderDao.insertFailedRecord(retryRecords);
        retryFileWriterToDB.write(retryRecords);
    }
}


@Override
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    errorFileWriter.open(executionContext);
    processedFileWriter.open(executionContext);
    //((ItemStream) retryFileWriter).open(executionContext);
}

@Override
public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    errorFileWriter.update(executionContext);
    processedFileWriter.update(executionContext);
    //((ItemStream) retryFileWriter).update(executionContext);
}

@Override
public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
    errorFileWriter.close();
    processedFileWriter.close();
    //((ItemStream) retryFileWriter).close();
}
```

}

Rest all code is same,as pasted in question. In batchCOnfig file I just change return type of jdbcitemwriter and in Compositewriter class I have autowired this jdbcitemwriter, like this
`@Autowired @Qualifier("retryFileWriterToDB") private ItemWriter<ChargeBack> retryFileWriterToDB;` 
and used this in composite writer class as

```
        retryFileWriterToDB.write(retryRecords);
```